# How do I make the "change order" button appear in SharePoint 2010?

Tags: sharepoint-2010, sharepoint-listtemplate

How do I make the "change order" button appear in SharePoint 2010?

I have followed a guide that allowed me to add `OrderedList="TRUE"` to my list template. This makes it possible to select "Allow users to order items in this view" for my view. But the change order button is still missing. **Any idears on what I am missing?**

I am using SharePoint 2010 and the guide is from 2006, so that might explain why it doesn't just work.

[The guide from tech-archive.net](http://www.tech-archive.net/Archive/SharePoint/microsoft.public.sharepoint.windowsservices/2006-05/msg00978.html).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I created a little console app to help me set the OrderedList attribute.

```
class Program {

    public static SPSite GetAdminSPSite() {
        SPSite spsite = null;
        SPSecurity.RunWithElevatedPrivileges(delegate() {
            spsite = new SPSite("http://sharepointdev");
        });

        return spsite;
    }

    static void Main(string[] args) {

        if (args.Length != 2) {
            Console.WriteLine("Missing sitename parameter and the list name.");
            return;
        }

        string sitename = args[0];
        string listname = args[1];

        using (SPSite site = GetAdminSPSite()) {

            using (SPWeb web = site.OpenWeb("ClientSites/" + sitename)) {

                SPList list = web.Lists[listname];
                list.Ordered = true;
                list.Update();

            }
        }

    }
}
```

Once that is run then you need to modify the view as @Jeff Smith says.

Comment: Thanks a lot. I no longer have access to the SharePoint solution, so I'll accept this as an answer. So I'm trusting that it works. =)

Comment: Hello Jan, this worked for me in SharePoint 2007. So, if it's changed in SharePoint 2010 then hopefully this a pointer in the right direction. I didn't notice the SharePoint 2010 references yesterday, which is downright embarrassing. Sorry.

Answer (score 2):

Not sure if you tried this already, but in SP 2007 after you deploy your list adding the OrderedList=TRUE attribute, you still need to modify the view and under sorting you'll see a new option "Allow user to sort items in this view". The "Change Order" button doesn't appear until you set that option to "Yes".

Comment: I had alredy changed the "Allow users to order items in this view" to "Yes", so unfortunately this isn't the answer.